# BASH create filename form variables

Tags: bash

I want to create a filename for redirecting output to.

eg:

```
ls -lash > $filename
```

All the variables are set.. 
So far I've tried the following:

```
filename=`echo $site . "_location_" . $address . "_" .  $timestamp . ".txt"` 

filename=$site . "_location_" . $address . "_" .  $timestamp . ".txt" 

filename="$site_location_$address_$timestamp.txt"
```

None have worked..  How do I get a file named like:

**site1_location_northeast_071218142325.txt**

Thanks

Comment: The dot (`.`) is the string concatenation operator in PHP, not in shell script.

Comment: Side note: As answers have pointed out, you don't need command substitution here. When you do though, use the modern form `$(command)` rather than `\`command\``. `$()` is much easier to read and can be conveniently nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is:

```
filename="${site}_location_${address}_${timestamp}.txt"
```

The curly braces around variable names help Bash know you want to replace the value of variables `$site` and `$address`. Otherwise, because `_` is a valid character in variable names, it thinks you want the use the variables `$site_location_` and `$address_` (that do not exist.)

Comment: Thanks both comments help.. this just had slightly more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Just use string interpolation.

```
filename="${site}_location_${address}_${timestamp}.txt"
```

The braces prevent the `_` from being treated as part of the preceding parameter name (or more precisely, they delimit the enclosed string as the parameter name).